# Use RDD.foreach to Create a Dataframe and execute actions on the Dataframe in Spark scala

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, out-of-memory, executor

I'm trying to read a config file in spark read.textfile which basically contains my tables list. my task is to iterate through the table list and convert Avro to ORC format. please find my below code snippet which will do the logic.

```scala
val tableList = spark.read.textFile('tables.txt')
tableList.collect().foreach(tblName => {
val df = spark.read.format("avro").load(inputPath+ "/" + tblName)
df.write.format("orc").mode("overwrite").save(outputPath+"/"+tblName)})
```

Please find my configurations below

> DriverMemory: 4GB
>
> ExecutorMemory: 10GB
>
> NoOfExecutors: 5
>
> Input DataSize: 45GB

My question here is this will execute in Executor or Driver? This will throw Out of Memory Error ? Please comment your suggestions.

```scala
val tableList = spark.read.textFile('tables.txt')

tableList.collect().foreach(tblName => {

val df = spark.read.format("avro").load(inputPath+ "/" + tblName)

df.write.format("orc").mode("overwrite").save(outputPath+"/"+tblName)}

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re:

> will this execute in Executor or Driver?

Once you call tableList.collect(), the contents of 'tables.txt' will be brought to the Driver application. If it is well within the Driver Memory it should be alright. 
However the save operation on Dataframe would be executed on executor.

Re:

> This will throw Out of Memory Error ?

Have you faced one ? IMO, unless your tables.txt is too huge you should be alright.I am assuming Input data size as 45 GB is the data in the tables mentioned in tables.txt.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes @Amit the 45 GB data is actual table data not the size of tables.txt

Comment: okay, If you think my answer has answered your question, please mark question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to eliminate the collect since it is an action therefore all the data from your 45gb file is loaded in memory. You can try something like this

```
val tableList = spark.read.textFile('tables.txt')
tableList.foreach(tblName => {
val df = spark.read.format("avro").load(inputPath+ "/" + tblName)
df.write.format("orc").mode("overwrite").save(outputPath+"/"+tblName)})
```